# Dictionary Sorting based on lower dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with an API that returns values in this format:

```
raw = [{'Name': 'Erica','Value':12},{'Name':'Sam','Value':8},{'Name':'Joe','Value':60}]
```

I am trying to return the 'name' of the people with the top 2 'values':

```
result = ['Joe','Erica']
```

What is the most efficient way to complete this?

Comment: Where is your *current* way, and how do you think it could be more efficient? Also, why do you think it needs to be?

Comment: Why are you using a list of dicts instead of a single dict mapping names to values?

Comment: @tobias_k This is the result generated by the API (that I do not control) and thus is the starting data I have to work with

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
raw = [{'Name': 'Erica','Value':12},{'Name':'Sam','Value':8},{'Name':'Joe','Value':60}]

raw.sort(key=lambda d: d['Value'], reverse=True)

result = []
for i in range(2):
    result.append(raw[i]['Name'])

print(result) # => ['Joe', 'Erica']
```

print(result)

Try this.

Comment: I am using Python 3.x+ and I am getting a syntax error at d in line 2. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know, this code works for me on both Python 2.7.10 and 3.5.0. What is your version and can you comment here the error?